# Entity framework C#, Update on DataBase occurred once in same build

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to update on the database using entity framework DB first when I'm using this query the data was updated only the first time or first call but when call this function again to update on database second time in the same build this function does not save the changes.
Please any Idea

```
agent.Balance = agent.Balance - Convert.ToDouble(USDBalance);
db.Entry(agent).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: How do you obtain agent in the first place?

Comment: Please share the complete function for better understanding.

Comment: @Stefan this way my dear
 `var agent = db.AgentAccounts.Include(b => b.AspNetUser).FirstOrDefault(b => b.UserId == userid);`

Comment: @Rahul Pandey
I fixed this bug 
this object actually updated in each time
but because I call the helper method before and declare an object of entity 
and after save changes for agent model 
I called the helper method again and insert fee to agent balance 
in this time the entity will update that called when the helper declared 
so the old value before the first update will update

Comment: You're welcome, sorry I left :-)

Comment: Interestingly, it should work. Can you verify all the necessary fields (identifiers) are set on the second run?